# C print 1-10, something wrong

Tags: c, arrays, count, increment

I have a C program, that's simple enough, but I'm fairly bad at using pointers intelligently.  If anybody could help me with this I'd really appreciate it.  It has two functions then the main.  The first function creates an array with 10 ints 1-10.  The second function prints out that array.  Thanks,

```
#include<stdio.h>

//function to create array of 10 ints
int* myArray(void)
{
int array[10], i;

for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    array[i] = i + 1;
}
return array;
}


//function to printout the array of 10 ints
void printArray(void)
{
int *array = myArray();
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
printf("%d ", array[i]);
}
}

//my main
int main()
{
myArray();
printArray();

}
```

The output I currently get is 1 1 2 3078316 5 6 3078824 257921824 1905931270 -2
pretty messed up lol.

Comment: This has nothing to do with"pointers" per se.  Look at cegfault's response below.  The problem is that you've defined "int array[10]" as a *local* variable ... and local variables *cease to exist* when you exit their scope.  "malloc()" (allocate the variable from the heap, instead of locally from the stack) is one way to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning a local variable from the function `myArray`.  Declaring `int array[10]` will put `array` on the stack, and gets destroyed when `myArray` returns.  This means `myArray` is returning an invalid pointer.

If you need to create an array within a function, use `malloc`.  That is:

```
int *array = (int *)malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
```

Note that at some point in time in the future you will need to `free()` the array. For example, in `printArray`:

```
int *array = myArray();
/* do some stuff with array */
free(array);
```